# Enviar lista js a un controlador Spring Java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

Espero recibir un lista en mi controlador que es enviado por **ajax**, en **Java** pero me sale un error:

> Non-type collection, es decir no coincide.

¿alguna otra forma de parsarlo?

**JavaScript**

```
var itms = [];
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj['cantidadD'] = i;
    obj['unidadD'] = 'kg';
    itms.push(obj);
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'genimp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {itm: itms},
    success: function (r) {

    }
});
```

**Controlador**

```
//public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> genfacturaimp(List itm){
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> genfacturaimp(ArrayList itm){
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
    map.put("fn", itm.size());
    map.put("l", 1);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Prueba a incluir @RequestBody antes de ArrayList itm

Comment: me sale un error en el parametro, error 400

Answer (score 0):

Tu controlador espera una lista, pero tu código **JavaScript** envía un objeto:

```
...
data: {itm:itms}
...
```

Si envías directamente el **array** creado:

```
... 
data: itms
...
```

Debería funcionar.

Comment: se arregla el error, pero no me da nada,no se puede parsear a String ni JSon, tampoco se puede parsear a List, `itms[0][cantidadD]=1&itms[0][unidadD]=kg` teniendo datos existentes, o ¿tendrás alguna forma de extraer los datos?

Comment: Actualiza tu código para ver cómo estás parseando